# kuma.io demo is failed with status code 503

Tags: kubernetes, devops, envoyproxy, sidecar, kuma

I have tried kuma.io product which is an open-source project for envoy proxy and security injection to sidecar pod in k8s environment. I installed there is demo after installation with

https://kuma.io/docs/0.5.1/quickstart/kubernetes/

I deployed this demo example to the k8s and forward the port:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/frontend -n kuma-demo 8080:8080

127.0.0.1:8080
```

and it gives this error

[kuma failed 503](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3dDp.png)

If any idea you have would be very nice!
Thanks

And here is the logs of pods init and sidecar containers

```
kubectl logs kuma-demo-app-94cdcfd8c-d5z4f -c kuma-fe -n kuma-demo
Starting up http-server, serving /dist
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://10.240.0.77:8080
Unhandled requests will be served from: http://backend:3001
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
[Mon Jun 08 2020 14:49:59 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)]  "GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
[Mon Jun 08 2020 14:49:59 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)]  "GET /js/app.163854c8.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
[Mon Jun 08 2020 14:49:59 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)]  "GET /css/app.92b097f8.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
[Mon Jun 08 2020 14:49:59 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)]  "GET /js/chunk-vendors.1eee84b8.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
[Mon Jun 08 2020 14:49:59 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)]  "GET /css/chunk-vendors.96abecf8.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
[Mon Jun 08 2020 14:50:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)]  "GET /items?q" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
[Mon Jun 08 2020 14:50:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)]  "GET /img/kuma-logo.90b6e909.svg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
```

second one

```
kubectl logs kuma-demo-app-94cdcfd8c-d5z4f -c kuma-sidecar -n kuma-demo
2020-06-08T14:31:38.710Z    INFO    Skipping reading config from file
2020-06-08T14:31:38.710Z    INFO    kuma-dp.run effective configuration {"config": "controlPlane:\n  apiServer:\n    url: http://kuma-control-plane.kuma-system:5681\ndataplane:\n  mesh: default\n  name: kuma-demo-app-94cdcfd8c-d5z4f.kuma-demo\n  drainTime: 30s\ndataplaneRuntime:\n  binaryPath: envoy\n  dataplaneTokenPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token\n"}
2020-06-08T14:31:38.721Z    INFO    kuma-dp.run picked a free port for Envoy Admin API to listen on {"port": "9901"}
2020-06-08T14:31:38.721Z    INFO    kuma-dp.run generated Envoy configuration will be stored in a temporary directory   {"dir": "/tmp/kuma-dp-127218165"}
2020-06-08T14:31:38.721Z    INFO    kuma-dp.run starting Kuma DP    {"version": "0.5.1"}
2020-06-08T14:31:38.726Z    INFO    accesslogs-server   starting Access Log Server  {"address": "unix:///tmp/kuma-access-logs-kuma-demo-app-94cdcfd8c-d5z4f.kuma-demo-default.sock"}
2020-06-08T14:31:38.760Z    INFO    kuma-dp.run.envoy   starting Envoy
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:255] initializing epoch 0 (hot restart version=disabled)
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:257] statically linked extensions:
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.filters.network: envoy.client_ssl_auth, envoy.echo, envoy.ext_authz, envoy.filters.network.client_ssl_auth, envoy.filters.network.direct_response, envoy.filters.network.dubbo_proxy, envoy.filters.network.echo, envoy.filters.network.ext_authz, envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager, envoy.filters.network.kafka_broker, envoy.filters.network.local_ratelimit, envoy.filters.network.mongo_proxy, envoy.filters.network.mysql_proxy, envoy.filters.network.ratelimit, envoy.filters.network.rbac, envoy.filters.network.redis_proxy, envoy.filters.network.sni_cluster, envoy.filters.network.tcp_proxy, envoy.filters.network.thrift_proxy, envoy.filters.network.zookeeper_proxy, envoy.http_connection_manager, envoy.mongo_proxy, envoy.ratelimit, envoy.redis_proxy, envoy.tcp_proxy
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.filters.listener: envoy.filters.listener.http_inspector, envoy.filters.listener.original_dst, envoy.filters.listener.original_src, envoy.filters.listener.proxy_protocol, envoy.filters.listener.tls_inspector, envoy.listener.http_inspector, envoy.listener.original_dst, envoy.listener.original_src, envoy.listener.proxy_protocol, envoy.listener.tls_inspector
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.dubbo_proxy.serializers: dubbo.hessian2
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.clusters: envoy.cluster.eds, envoy.cluster.logical_dns, envoy.cluster.original_dst, envoy.cluster.static, envoy.cluster.strict_dns, envoy.clusters.aggregate, envoy.clusters.dynamic_forward_proxy, envoy.clusters.redis
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.thrift_proxy.protocols: auto, binary, binary/non-strict, compact, twitter
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.grpc_credentials: envoy.grpc_credentials.aws_iam, envoy.grpc_credentials.default, envoy.grpc_credentials.file_based_metadata
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.transport_sockets.downstream: envoy.transport_sockets.alts, envoy.transport_sockets.raw_buffer, envoy.transport_sockets.tap, envoy.transport_sockets.tls, raw_buffer, tls
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.health_checkers: envoy.health_checkers.redis
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.dubbo_proxy.route_matchers: default
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.thrift_proxy.transports: auto, framed, header, unframed
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.retry_priorities: envoy.retry_priorities.previous_priorities
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.filters.http: envoy.buffer, envoy.cors, envoy.csrf, envoy.ext_authz, envoy.fault, envoy.filters.http.adaptive_concurrency, envoy.filters.http.aws_lambda, envoy.filters.http.aws_request_signing, envoy.filters.http.buffer, envoy.filters.http.cache, envoy.filters.http.cors, envoy.filters.http.csrf, envoy.filters.http.dynamic_forward_proxy, envoy.filters.http.dynamo, envoy.filters.http.ext_authz, envoy.filters.http.fault, envoy.filters.http.grpc_http1_bridge, envoy.filters.http.grpc_http1_reverse_bridge, envoy.filters.http.grpc_json_transcoder, envoy.filters.http.grpc_stats, envoy.filters.http.grpc_web, envoy.filters.http.gzip, envoy.filters.http.header_to_metadata, envoy.filters.http.health_check, envoy.filters.http.ip_tagging, envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn, envoy.filters.http.lua, envoy.filters.http.on_demand, envoy.filters.http.original_src, envoy.filters.http.ratelimit, envoy.filters.http.rbac, envoy.filters.http.router, envoy.filters.http.squash, envoy.filters.http.tap, envoy.grpc_http1_bridge, envoy.grpc_json_transcoder, envoy.grpc_web, envoy.gzip, envoy.health_check, envoy.http_dynamo_filter, envoy.ip_tagging, envoy.lua, envoy.rate_limit, envoy.router, envoy.squash
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.transport_sockets.upstream: envoy.transport_sockets.alts, envoy.transport_sockets.raw_buffer, envoy.transport_sockets.tap, envoy.transport_sockets.tls, raw_buffer, tls
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.thrift_proxy.filters: envoy.filters.thrift.rate_limit, envoy.filters.thrift.router
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   http_cache_factory: envoy.extensions.http.cache.simple
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.access_loggers: envoy.access_loggers.file, envoy.access_loggers.http_grpc, envoy.access_loggers.tcp_grpc, envoy.file_access_log, envoy.http_grpc_access_log, envoy.tcp_grpc_access_log
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.filters.udp_listener: envoy.filters.udp.dns_filter, envoy.filters.udp_listener.udp_proxy
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.tracers: envoy.dynamic.ot, envoy.lightstep, envoy.tracers.datadog, envoy.tracers.dynamic_ot, envoy.tracers.lightstep, envoy.tracers.opencensus, envoy.tracers.xray, envoy.tracers.zipkin, envoy.zipkin
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.udp_listeners: raw_udp_listener
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.dubbo_proxy.protocols: dubbo
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.dubbo_proxy.filters: envoy.filters.dubbo.router
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.retry_host_predicates: envoy.retry_host_predicates.omit_canary_hosts, envoy.retry_host_predicates.omit_host_metadata, envoy.retry_host_predicates.previous_hosts
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.resource_monitors: envoy.resource_monitors.fixed_heap, envoy.resource_monitors.injected_resource
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.resolvers: envoy.ip
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.746][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:259]   envoy.stats_sinks: envoy.dog_statsd, envoy.metrics_service, envoy.stat_sinks.dog_statsd, envoy.stat_sinks.hystrix, envoy.stat_sinks.metrics_service, envoy.stat_sinks.statsd, envoy.statsd
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.772][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:340] admin address: 127.0.0.1:9901
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.774][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:459] runtime: layers:
  - name: base
    static_layer:
      {}
  - name: admin
    admin_layer:
      {}
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.775][14][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:103] loading tracing configuration
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.775][14][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:69] loading 0 static secret(s)
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.775][14][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:75] loading 2 cluster(s)
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.837][14][warning][config] [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:92] StreamAggregatedResources gRPC config stream closed: 14, no healthy upstream
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.837][14][warning][config] [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:54] Unable to establish new stream
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.837][14][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:79] loading 0 listener(s)
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.837][14][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:129] loading stats sink configuration
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.839][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:554] starting main dispatch loop
[2020-06-08 14:31:39.841][14][info][upstream] [source/common/upstream/cluster_manager_impl.cc:167] cm init: initializing cds
[2020-06-08 14:31:40.915][14][info][upstream] [source/common/upstream/cds_api_impl.cc:77] cds: add 7 cluster(s), remove 2 cluster(s)
[2020-06-08 14:31:40.933][14][info][upstream] [source/common/upstream/cds_api_impl.cc:93] cds: add/update cluster 'frontend.kuma-demo.svc:8080'
[2020-06-08 14:31:40.953][14][info][upstream] [source/common/upstream/cds_api_impl.cc:93] cds: add/update cluster 'postgres.kuma-demo.svc:5432'
[2020-06-08 14:31:40.970][14][info][upstream] [source/common/upstream/cds_api_impl.cc:93] cds: add/update cluster 'redis.kuma-demo.svc:6379'
[2020-06-08 14:31:40.981][14][info][upstream] [source/common/upstream/cds_api_impl.cc:93] cds: add/update cluster 'direct_access'
[2020-06-08 14:31:40.990][14][info][upstream] [source/common/upstream/cds_api_impl.cc:93] cds: add/update cluster 'pass_through'
[2020-06-08 14:31:41.000][14][info][upstream] [source/common/upstream/cds_api_impl.cc:93] cds: add/update cluster 'localhost:8080'
[2020-06-08 14:31:41.017][14][info][upstream] [source/common/upstream/cds_api_impl.cc:93] cds: add/update cluster 'backend.kuma-demo.svc:3001'
[2020-06-08 14:31:41.017][14][info][upstream] [source/common/upstream/cluster_manager_impl.cc:145] cm init: initializing secondary clusters
[2020-06-08 14:31:42.378][14][info][upstream] [source/common/upstream/cluster_manager_impl.cc:171] cm init: all clusters initialized
[2020-06-08 14:31:42.378][14][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:533] all clusters initialized. initializing init manager
[2020-06-08 14:31:42.381][14][warning][misc] [source/common/protobuf/utility.cc:198] Using deprecated option 'envoy.api.v2.Listener.use_original_dst' from file listener.proto. This configuration will be removed from Envoy soon. Please see https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/deprecated for details.
[2020-06-08 14:31:42.385][14][info][upstream] [source/server/lds_api.cc:76] lds: add/update listener 'catch_all'
[2020-06-08 14:31:42.400][14][warning][misc] [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/source/extensions/common/_virtual_includes/utility_lib/extensions/common/utility.h:65] Using deprecated extension name 'envoy.router' for 'envoy.filters.http.router'. This name will be removed from Envoy soon. Please see https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/deprecated for details.
[2020-06-08 14:31:42.401][14][info][upstream] [source/server/lds_api.cc:76] lds: add/update listener 'inbound:10.240.0.77:8080'
[2020-06-08 14:31:42.415][14][warning][misc] [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/source/extensions/common/_virtual_includes/utility_lib/extensions/common/utility.h:65] Using deprecated extension name 'envoy.router' for 'envoy.filters.http.router'. This name will be removed from Envoy soon. Please see https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/deprecated for details.
[2020-06-08 14:31:42.417][14][info][upstream] [source/server/lds_api.cc:76] lds: add/update listener 'outbound:10.0.61.163:3001'
[2020-06-08 14:31:42.431][14][warning][misc] [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/source/extensions/common/_virtual_includes/utility_lib/extensions/common/utility.h:65] Using deprecated extension name 'envoy.router' for 'envoy.filters.http.router'. This name will be removed from Envoy soon. Please see https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/deprecated for details.
[2020-06-08 14:31:42.432][14][info][upstream] [source/server/lds_api.cc:76] lds: add/update listener 'outbound:10.0.35.179:8080'
[2020-06-08 14:31:42.434][14][info][upstream] [source/server/lds_api.cc:76] lds: add/update listener 'outbound:10.0.101.120:5432'
[2020-06-08 14:31:42.436][14][info][upstream] [source/server/lds_api.cc:76] lds: add/update listener 'outbound:10.0.83.94:6379'
[2020-06-08 14:31:42.447][14][info][config] [source/server/listener_manager_impl.cc:725] all dependencies initialized. starting workers
[2020-06-08 14:46:42.437][14][info][main] [source/server/drain_manager_impl.cc:68] shutting down parent after drain
```

third one

```
kubectl logs kuma-demo-app-94cdcfd8c-d5z4f -c kuma-init -n kuma-demo
    Environment:
    ------------
    ENVOY_PORT=
    ISTIO_INBOUND_INTERCEPTION_MODE=
    ISTIO_INBOUND_TPROXY_MARK=
    ISTIO_INBOUND_TPROXY_ROUTE_TABLE=
    ISTIO_INBOUND_PORTS=
    ISTIO_LOCAL_EXCLUDE_PORTS=
    ISTIO_SERVICE_CIDR=
    ISTIO_SERVICE_EXCLUDE_CIDR=

Variables:
----------
PROXY_PORT=15001
INBOUND_CAPTURE_PORT=15001
PROXY_UID=5678
INBOUND_INTERCEPTION_MODE=REDIRECT
INBOUND_TPROXY_MARK=1337
INBOUND_TPROXY_ROUTE_TABLE=133
INBOUND_PORTS_INCLUDE=*
INBOUND_PORTS_EXCLUDE=
OUTBOUND_IP_RANGES_INCLUDE=*
OUTBOUND_IP_RANGES_EXCLUDE=
KUBEVIRT_INTERFACES=
ENABLE_INBOUND_IPV6=

+ iptables -t nat -N ISTIO_REDIRECT
+ iptables -t nat -A ISTIO_REDIRECT -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 15001
+ iptables -t nat -N ISTIO_IN_REDIRECT
+ iptables -t nat -A ISTIO_IN_REDIRECT -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 15001
+ '[' -n '*' ']'
+ '[' REDIRECT = TPROXY ']'
+ table=nat
+ iptables -t nat -N ISTIO_INBOUND
+ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j ISTIO_INBOUND
+ '[' '*' == '*' ']'
+ iptables -t nat -A ISTIO_INBOUND -p tcp --dport 22 -j RETURN
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' REDIRECT = TPROXY ']'
+ iptables -t nat -A ISTIO_INBOUND -p tcp -j ISTIO_IN_REDIRECT
+ iptables -t nat -N ISTIO_OUTPUT
+ iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j ISTIO_OUTPUT
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ iptables -t nat -A ISTIO_OUTPUT -o lo '!' -d 127.0.0.1/32 -j ISTIO_REDIRECT
+ for uid in '${PROXY_UID}'
+ iptables -t nat -A ISTIO_OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 5678 -j RETURN
+ for gid in '${PROXY_GID}'
+ iptables -t nat -A ISTIO_OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner 5678 -j RETURN
+ iptables -t nat -A ISTIO_OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -j RETURN
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' '*' == '*' ']'
+ iptables -t nat -A ISTIO_OUTPUT -j ISTIO_REDIRECT
+ set +o nounset
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ ip6tables -F INPUT
+ ip6tables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
+ ip6tables -A INPUT -i lo -d ::1 -j ACCEPT
+ ip6tables -A INPUT -j REJECT
+ dump
+ iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Jun  8 14:30:01 2020
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jun  8 14:30:01 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Jun  8 14:30:01 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:ISTIO_INBOUND - [0:0]
:ISTIO_IN_REDIRECT - [0:0]
:ISTIO_OUTPUT - [0:0]
:ISTIO_REDIRECT - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -j ISTIO_INBOUND
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -j ISTIO_OUTPUT
-A ISTIO_INBOUND -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j RETURN
-A ISTIO_INBOUND -p tcp -j ISTIO_IN_REDIRECT
-A ISTIO_IN_REDIRECT -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 15001
-A ISTIO_OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.1/32 -o lo -j ISTIO_REDIRECT
-A ISTIO_OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 5678 -j RETURN
-A ISTIO_OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner 5678 -j RETURN
-A ISTIO_OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -j RETURN
-A ISTIO_OUTPUT -j ISTIO_REDIRECT
-A ISTIO_REDIRECT -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 15001
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jun  8 14:30:01 2020
+ ip6tables-save
# Generated by ip6tables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Jun  8 14:30:01 2020
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d ::1/128 -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jun  8 14:30:01 2020
```

Comment: share logs from kuma pod

Comment: I appended logs to the question above